# take specific numbers from multiple .txt files and add them up seperatly

Tags: python, addition, txt

I have multiple directories with .txt files with numbers in them. For example
`('0.742,0.128,0.025,0.105')`.
With the code below I think I made it so that Python can see the number's separately from each other, and it shows like this
`('0.742', '0.128', '0.025', '0.105')`

```
    name_dirs = os.listdir(NAME)     
    for c in name_dirs:
        print(c)
        path = os.path.join(NAME, c)
        numbers = os.path.join(path, 'numbers.txt')
        print(numbers)
        with open(numbers) as f:
            contents = f.readlines()
            print(contents)
        for n in contents:  
            numps = n.split(',')
            print(numps)
```

I have multiple directories it has to go through, and I have to add up all the first number's, all the second number's and so on.
Let's say the numbers in the .txt files are following:

`dir 1 = ('0.742', '0.128', '0.025', '0.105')`
`dir 2 = ('0.801', '0.014', '0.136', '0.049')`
`dir 3 = ('0.242', '0.458', '0.300', '0.000')`

I have to add the first numbers from every dir so `0.742 , 0.801 and 0.242`
this must also be done for the second, third and fourth group. This will give me 4 numbers that I can use later.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
name_dirs = os.listdir(NAME)     
result = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    for c in name_dirs:
        print(c)
        path = os.path.join(NAME, c)
        numbers = os.path.join(path, 'numbers.txt')
        print(numbers)
        with open(numbers) as f:
            contents = f.readlines()
            print(contents)
        for n in contents:  
            numps = n.split(',')
            for i in range(len(numps)):
                result[i] += float(numps[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what eventually worked

```
name_dirs = os.listdir(NAME)
c = 1
    while c < number of maps in dirs:
        for b in name_dirs:
            print(b)
            path = os.path.join(NAME, b)
            numbers = os.path.join(path, 'numbers.txt')
            print(numbers)
            with open(numbers) as f:
                contents = f.readlines()
                print(contents)
            for n in contents:
                numps = n.split(' , ')
                print(numps)

            num_1 = nums[0]
            print(num_1)
            with open('.txt file directory for all num_1', 'a+') as f:
                f.write(num_1)
                if c < number of maps in dirs:
                    f.write(", ")
            num_2 = nums[1]
            print(num_2)
            with open('.txt file directory for all num_2’, 'a+') as f:
                f.write(num_2)
                if c < number of maps in dirs:
                    f.write(", ")
            num_3 = nums[2]
            print(num_3)
            with open('.txt file directory for all num_3’, 'a+') as f:
                f.write(num_3)
                if c < number of maps in dirs:
                    f.write(", ")
            num_4 = nums[3]
            print(num_4)
            with open('.txt file directory for all num_4’, 'a+') as f:
                f.write(num_4)
                if c < number of maps in dirs:
                    f.write(", ")
            c += 1
```